# Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library get verification record

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library ( https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet ).

I want to call this API method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-list-verificationdnsrecords?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains/{domain-name}/verificationDnsRecords
```

I try to do the following:

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
     new QueryOption("domain-name", domain)
};

var r = await graphClient.Domains.Request(options).Select(p => p.VerificationDnsRecords).GetAsync();
```

But I get an error like "Unknown domain-name" parameter. I tried `id` instead of `domain-name` and get the same.

What is wrong and how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution how to set domain name. It should be:

```
await graphClient.Domains[domain].VerificationDnsRecords.Request().GetAsync();
```

without any `QueryOption`